# Probability - inductive proof

Tags: probability

Let $A_1,...,A_n$ are given events. Prove that $P(A_1 \cap ... \cap A_n)=P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)...P(A_n|A_1\cap ... \cap A_{n-1}).$

How to prove this statement by induction?

Comment: Hint: prove the two-variable case and use in the induction step.

Answer (score 1):

Assume it is true for $n:$
$$P(A_1\cap \cdots A_n)=P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1) \cdots P(A_n|A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_{n-1})$$
For $n+1:$
$$P(A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_n \color{red}{\cap} A_{n+1})=P(A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_n)P(A_{n+1}|A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_n)=$$
$$P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)\cdots P(A_n|A_1\cap \cdots A_{n-1})P(A_{n+1}|A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_n).$$