# Multiplication Theorem of Probability

Tags: probability

See the book [*Schaum's Outline of Probability*](https://math24.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/schaums-probability.pdf), Chapter-$4$, Page-$55$.

[image]

.

How does the example $4.3$ comply with the Corollary $4.3$?

Can someone elaborate to show how they applied the corollary to that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383157/probability-inductive-proof/2383175#2383175).

For the second, let $A_1, A_2, A_3$ be the first, second and third item nondefective, respectively. Then:
$$\begin{align}P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)=&\color{red}{P(A_1)}\cdot \color{green}{P(A_2|A_1)}\cdot \color{blue}{P(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)}=\\
=&\color{red}{\frac{8}{12}}\cdot \color{green}{\frac{7}{11}}\cdot \color{blue}{\frac{6}{10}} = \frac{14}{55}.\end{align}$$
Note: "The items are drawn at random from the lot one after the other" implies the items are taken without replacement.

Comment: So, this is heuristics, not mathematics?

Comment: What do you mean by "heuristic"? Is not the solution method based on the Theorem 4.2 and the Corollary 4.3, how can it be not mathematical?

Comment: Can we mathematically show, for instance, that $P(A_2|A_1) = \frac{7}{11}$ or $P(A_3|A_1 \cap A_2) = \frac{6}{10}$ ?

Comment: yes, $12-1=11$, $8-1=7$, hence the result. I am sure you can write down similar mathematical expressions for the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_i$ be the event that the ith item you draw is not defective. Now, $p(A_1)$ is the probability that the first item is not defective. By the time you are picking the second item, you already know that the first item is not defective, so $p(A_2/A_1)$ gives you the conditional probability that even $A_2$ occurs given that $A_1$ has already occurred. Finally, by the time that you picked the third item, the first two items are already not defective, so $p(A_3/A_1\cap A_2)$ gives you the appropriate conditional probability. From corollary 4.3,

$p(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$ = probability that all 3 events $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$ have occurred together is =  $p(A_1)$ x $p(A_2/A_1)$ x $p(A_3/A_1\cap A_2)$ = $\frac{8}{12} \frac{7}{11} \frac{6}{10}.$

Comment: So, this is heuristics, not mathematics?

Comment: You are applying a mathematical construct to a practical problem. There is no ambiguity in the mathematical construct. There maybe heuristics or assumptions that you make when you model your problem.